# Is it a good idea to watch /zookeeper/config change to update curator connect string?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I want my zookeeper client (Curator Framework) to keep track of up-to-date servers when quorum config changes, so I came up the idea to add a listener (Curator NodeCache) to watch /zookeeper/config. 
When quorum config changes, client will receive events and get the updated value in /zookeeper/config then extract the latest full connect string that contains all up-to-date zookeeper nodes.

Accordingly, the curator client uses a EnsembleProvider instead of connect string. When quorum changes, the EnsembleProvider is always aware of the latest server list so it can provide the correct connect string.
The pseudo code looks like this

```
AtomicReference<List<String>> connectStringHolder = new AtomicReference<>(new ArrayList<>());

// initial connect string
connectStringHolder.get().add("<initial server string>");

CuratorFrameworkFactory.Builder builder = CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder();

// EnsembleProvider instead of plain connect string
builder.ensembleProvider(new EnsembleProvider() {
    // when zookeeper client needs a connect string
    public String getConnectionString() {
        final String join = String.join(",", connectStringHolder.get());
        return join;
    }
});

final CuratorFramework curatorFramework = builder.build();
curatorFramework.start();

// watch changes on /zookeeper/config
NodeCache nodeCache = new NodeCache(curatorFramework,"/zookeeper/config");
nodeCache.getListenable().addListener(new NodeCacheListener() {
    @Override
    public void nodeChanged() throws Exception {
        final byte[] data = nodeCache.getCurrentData().getData();
        List<String> newServersFromConfig = extract(data);

        // update connectStringHolder
        connectStringHolder.set(strings);
    }
});
nodeCache.start();
```

Don't know if it is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Curator already tracks the config node for you (via `EnsembleTracker` internally). You can always get the current config via `CuratorFramework.getCurrentConfig()`. You don't need to do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Seems turn off `zk34CompatibilityMode` in `CuratorFrameworkFactory.Builder` will make it possible for curator client to keep track of latest quorum config.

Comment: zk34CompatibilityMode would only be on if you are using the ZK 3.4.x JAR. Make sure you use the correct versions of the libraries.